# When do the CF and OF get set during arithmetic operations?

Tags: assembly, x86

I can't find a reasonable formula for this. I know CF is used for unsigned arithmetic and OF for signed.

Please give some example arithmetic operations (like 5-7,7-5 etc.) along with the heuristic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034566/overflow-and-carry-flags-on-z80) contains C code to emulate the ADD, ADC, SUB and SBB instructions with the carry and overflow flags and a test.

Another possibly interesting related question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8053053/how-does-an-adder-perform-unsigned-integer-subtraction).

And you should be able to find this info in the official CPU documentation from Intel and AMD.