# (Assembly)How to set OF and ZF at once?

Tags: assembly

I'm supposed to set both OF and ZF flag but I must use one of these: 
**ADD, SUB, MUL or DIV** but just once. I can use everything else and it can generate other flags too, I know how to do just ZF or just OF and I do understand the theory but I just can't seem to generate them both in this exercise.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

EDIT: Solved

Comment: So what two numbers and what operation can you perform on them that would result in a zero and an overflow? This isn't as hard as you think. There's probably more than one solution. Remember: a CPU word is a finite number of bits (which is why OF exists).

Comment: Click "edit" under your question and paste the code to set "just ZF or just OF".

Comment: Is this an X-Y question? Those flags are tested after operations which affect them, by branch instructions. What is the point of contriving them? Usually (x86) the only flags you explicitly set are `DF` and `CF` because they affect subsequent instructions. (Also some processors have IRQ control flag).

Comment: @WeatherVane it's just an assignment to trigger both of them this way..

Comment: @lurker Yep, that's what I've been trying to figure out but no luck

Comment: Try     `mov ax, 0x8000` `add ax, 0x8000` . In this case both the signs are negative but when executed the sign of the result will be positive (result being 0x0000). In this case it should overflow and be zero. The carry flag should also be set of course.

Comment: @MichaelPetch thank you! :)

Comment: @lurker : that won't overflow but it will set the carry. You'll need two values that have the *same* sign bit and when added together yield an opposite sign. In this case to get zero you'll need two such values that also equal 0.

Comment: I know I had seen another SO answer that had a table that would help. Managed to find it in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8982549/3857942  . The question isn't really a duplicate but the answer is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this:

```
 mov ax, 0x8000
 add ax, 0x8000
```

This will trigger `ZF` since AX will now be zero.  This will also trigger `OF` since we have overflowed the maximum 16 bit value of `ax.`

Comment: this doesn't trigger OF

Comment: @SimonaChovancová is right, OF **is not** being set.

Comment: Hmm... Seems like it should.  16 bit or 32 bit machine?

Comment: It looks just like @MichaelPetch's comment :)

Comment: @DavidHoelzer it shouldn't (not the one from before the update), the carry into the sign is the same as the carry out of it (both 1) and by definition OF is the XOR between them

Comment: Makes sense, @Harold.  Thanks.

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez It is, after I realized my error. :)

Comment: 0x8000 plus 0x8000, 16 bit math the carry in is a zero the result of the msbit is a 0 with a carry out of 1, the carry in and the carry out dont match. Using the other way to determine it if the two msbits are the same and the result msbit is not then it is a signed overflow and that is the case here the two msbits are 1 the result is all zeros including the msbit, so signed overflow.