# Assembly x86 flags- overflow flag

Tags: assembly, flags

I just started learning assembly and I'm trying to understand how the different flags work.
Let's say I do this:

```
mov ax, 0xBFE8h
mov bx, 25DFh
add ax, bx
```

Shouldn't the overflow flag turn on? The value of the addition is 58,823 (in base 10), which is more then the 32,767 (a signed 16 bit value). 
I checked in the program and the flag doesn't turn on. Why is this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt.  You're looking for the Carry Flag (unsigned), not signed OverFlow.

Comment: In signed math (interpretation of values) you are doing -16408 + 9695 = negative + positive value can't overflow in the principle, as the result will be surely equal/between the original two values. OF is signed-math related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The overflow flag turns on when signed overflow occurs.  However, this is not the case in your code.  `0xbfe8` is larger than `0x8000` and thus negative in two's complement, representing −16408.  `0x25DF` is equal to 9695, their sum is −6713 which is not outside of the range −32768 to +32767, so no signed overflow occured and the overflow flag is cleared.

Comment: Surely this question is a duplicate of something.  I've been looking but haven't found an identical one with good answers yet.

Comment: @PeterCordes Maybe this one is going to be the canonical duplicate in the future.

Comment: Finally! I've been trying to understand this for a while, thanks!

Comment: This one is quite good: reference table of inputs / output / CF / OF for 8-bit add and sub: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965923/carry-overflow-subtraction-in-x86