# Can I use two complement for SUB instruction gameboy emulation?

Tags: emulation, z80, gameboy

Hello I'm writing an emulator for Game Boy.

And I'm struggling with SUB intruction

```
SUB a, 0x92
```

given `a = 0x90`.

What I am doing is :

```
0x90 + (-0x92)
```

I use 2 complement method for substraction.

```
-0x92 <=>
2_complement(0x92) <=>
2_complement(10010010) <=>
01101101 + 1 <=>
01101110
```

So the substraction is equivalent to the following addition:

```
 1001 0000 (0x90)
+0110 1110 (-0x92) 
 ---------
 1111 1110 (0xFE)
```

During the process, there is no carry and no half carry so I don't set the flags. And I think it's a mistake because other emulators (like [BGB](http://bgb.bircd.org/) does. 
Note that the result is correct, only the flags are incorrect.

So I suppose real processor doesn't use 2 complement method because there is no free way to retrieve carry and half-carry.

Still, can I use two complement for emulating the SUB instruction with flag handling, or should I rely on "classic" substraction logic ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Real CPUs do really rely on inversion of an argument while doing subtraction.

Note first that two's-complement is by itself another addition (you add 1 after inverting all bits), so doing exactly like that would be slow.

Let's look at adding just an inverted argument:

0x90 + (~0x92) = 0x90 + 0x6D = 0xFD and you get no carry. Off by 1 from correct result.

To fix the result, you must add another one, which is conveniently done by passing carry in = 1 to the adder. Thus, you must invert incoming carry just like you've done with the argument.
Not surprisingly, resulting carry is also inverted.

An example: subtract 0x12 from 0x34:
0x34 + (~0x12) + 1(inverted incoming carry) = 0x34 + 0xED + 1 = 0x122: no carry out (take inverted output carry) and correct result.
Incoming carry is 1: 0x34+0xED+0 = 0x121 (no carry out, result is less by 1).

There are, however, CPUs that don't invert incoming and resulting carry: those include 6502 (inverted carry inputs and outputs SBC command) and 32bit ARMs. They only invert argument.

Comment: I think probably the key part of this answer is: *resulting carry is also inverted*. So the original author is right that the additive form produces neither carry nor half-carry. But he should invert that result and **set** the carry and half carry flags. Is that a fair thing to say?

Answer (score 2):

You can find the answers to how add/sub work and carry/overflow flags are set here:

[My answer to: Overflow and Carry flags on Z80](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8037485/968261)

[My answer to: How does an adder perform unsigned integer subtraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8061989/968261)