# How can I know if the CF or the OF is on or off?

Tags: assembly, binary, flags, x86-16

```
10011100   +
01010000
---------
```

For this expression, how can I know what will be the CF and the OF after calculating the expression?

Comment: x86, I presume? And an 8-bit addition?

Comment: It'd be helpful to mention that (most likely) this is for x86. There's more to the CPU universe than just Intel, you know...

Comment: If you're trying to emulate the addition instruction (or subtraction or comparison), [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8037485/968261) should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you add them.

```
10011100   +
01010000
---------
11101100
```

For CF: was there a carry-out? Not in this case, so CF is zero.

For OF: is the carry into the signbit different from the carry-out? Not in this case, so OF is zero.

Comment: Can you explain what is a carry-out?

Comment: @user1718294 when you add numbers you get carries sometimes, the carry-out is the carry that "falls off the edge" (because the number has a fixed length).