# Should this be an overflow condition?

Tags: math, assembly, binary, emulation, cpu

I am trying to write a MOS 6502 8-bit emulator to better learn about CPUs.

I have implemented my ADC (add with carry) instruction thanks to a lot of help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034566/overflow-and-carry-flags-on-z80/8037485#comment18965304_8037485). My output was exactly as the question's answer's example output.

The problem is, I'm now not sure if there is a bug in that answer since I thought 255 + 1 would cause both a carry and an overflow (since 255 + 1 = 256, not 0).  With the approach taken in the answered question above, I only get a carry, not an overflow.

Which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. According to linked answer, overflow flag is set when you would have overflow with signed interpretation of numbers. (unsigned)255 = 0xff = (signed)-1 . And -1 + 1 = 0 has no overflow.

Comment: This is frustrating.  I was testing my code with this online 6502 emulator (http://e-tradition.net/bytes/6502/) and according to that - adding $FF to $01 should result in both a carry and an overflow. Not sure what to believe now!

Comment: @Garry You should be able to find a version of "Programming the 6502" by Rodnay Zaks online. In my copy (third edition, 1980) on page 23 it says "... the overflow flag is set by Exclusive ORing the carry-in and carry-out of bit 7 (the sign bit)." if that makes it any clearer.

Comment: @Garry I believe the emulator is broken. See it's code of `function opADC` it sets `fCAR` and `fOVF` in the same case.

Comment: Thanks Andrew/zch.  I've got that book too.  I think I'm just going to assume that the online emulator I've been using to test may be flawed as all things are pointing to my initial implementation being correct.